Number of Downloads of a particular Asset
We need to display the download count for each specific asset on its details page. Is there a way to show the number of downloads for each asset individually? For example, if I'm viewing the details page for Asset X, it should show the number of times Asset X has been downloaded, and if I'm on Asset Y's details page, it should display the download count for Asset Y.

It's not OOTB available. You may need to create a custom field in your asset model to store the download count and create a custom API or use existing hooks in the Content Hub to trigger an update to the download count.

We raised a feature request in Mar 2024 and Sitecore are tracking this under MONE-31422

You can use Audit API to read the number of times the asset was downloaded and display on the asset detail page using external component.
/api/audit/business/query/{{Asset_ID}}?event_type=asset.download.completed

This will return the number of times asset is downloaded in the total_items parameter as below.

Using above REST API, you can fetch the number of downloads for the asset on the asset details page and display it through external component. More details on the Audit endpoint API parameters can be found here.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.
